# Forwarding traffic from a DigitalOcean Load Balancer to a Kubernetes Service not working

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, digital-ocean

I created a kubernetes service that is exposed via `type: nodePort`. I can access the service in my browser if I enter http://PublicDropletIp:31433.

Now I want to use a DigitalOcean Load Balancer to forward traffic from port `80` to the service. So I set a rule for the Load Balancer to forward `http/80` to Droplet `http/31433`.

Unforutnatly this doesn't work. If I enter the load balancer IP in the browser I get: `503 Service Unavailable`.

Does anyone know how I can expose the service so that the Load Balancer can forward traffic to it?

Comment: Did you set the healthcheck of the LB correctly so it checks port 31433 instead of default port 80 ?

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue and ended up on this thread. If anyone else is looking, I resolved it by configuring the firewall on my server.

To answer the question above, the firewall should be configured to accept `tcp` connections from the load balancer's ip on port `31433`.

Comment: nice one, managed to resolve the same problem following this advice. [this](http://pix.toile-libre.org/?img=1604413620.png) is a screenshot, which might be helpful